# Unable to receive parameter in query string when redirected to other page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, query-string

Hi I am developing one application in java-script. I have two pages default.aspx and addnewitem.aspx. there is one html table in  default.aspx and one button. When i click on button i want to redirect to addnewitem.aspx page. I have some parameters to send in query string. I am able to redirect to addnewitem.aspx but page not found error i am getting. I am not sure why i am getting page not found error. I am trying as below.

```
function getValues() {
    var Title = "dfd";
    var PrimarySkills = "fdfd";
    var SecondarySkills = "dfdf";
    var url = "http://sites/APPSTEST/JobRequisitionApp/Pages/AddNewItem.aspx?Title=" + encodeURIComponent($(Title)) + "&PrimarySkills=" + encodeURIComponent($(PrimarySkills)) + "&SecondarySkills=" + encodeURIComponent($(SecondarySkills));
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

I am checking querystring in addnewitem.aspx as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var queryString = new Array();
        $(function () {
            if (queryString.length == 0) {
                if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                    var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                        var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                        var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                        queryString[key] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (queryString["Title"] != null && queryString["PrimarySkills"] != null) {
                var data = "<u>Values from QueryString</u><br /><br />";
                data += "<b>Title:</b> " + queryString["Title"] + " <b>PrimarySkills:</b> " + queryString["PrimarySkills"] + " <b>SecondarySkills:</b> " + queryString["SecondarySkills"];
                $("#lblData").html(data);
                alert(data);
            }
        });
</script>

"http://sites/APPSTEST/JobRequisitionApp/Pages/AddNewItem.aspx?Title=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&PrimarySkills=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&SecondarySkills=%5Bobject%20Object%5D"
```

I tried lot to fix this. May i know where i am doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Trying to browse the simple page URL on browser, and see page is found or not.

Comment: Thank you.. My both pages are .aspx? Will cookies work in this cases?

Comment: You well come. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the relative path in your `url` instead of hard coding the entire folder structure, which is probably incorrect since you are getting a 404. And you need to change the url every time you publish the site to the hosting enviroment when you hard code it like that.

So change

```
var url = "http://sites/APPSTEST/JobRequisitionApp/Pages/AddNewItem.aspx?Title=...
```

into

```
var url = "/AddNewItem.aspx?Title=...
```

if both the pages are in the same folder. Should `AddNewItem.aspx` be located in the `Pages` folder, you have to add that folder of course: `var url = "/Pages/AddNewItem.aspx?Title=...`